# PhpStorm 2021.1 throws "Error running 'ABCD'. Debugger extension not detected"

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, xdebug-3

This seems to be a PhpStorm EAP trait -same thing happened to me with 2020.3.

This is the php.ini config that worked for 2020...

```ini
[Xdebug]
zend_extension = /usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug-3.0.2.so
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port = 9001
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_log = /var/log/xdebug.log
xdebug.show_local_vars = 9
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = /var/log
output_buffering = off
```

...and this is what I am trying to use with 2021:

```ini
xdebug.remote_log = /var/log/xdebug.log
xdebug.show_local_vars = 9
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = /var/log
output_buffering = off
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.discover_client_host = true
xdebug.client_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port = 9001
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
```

PhpStorm's ports are set as 9001 and 9003. I'm up the walls again. Any ideas, please and thank you?

Comment: Please share more details - what do you do to trigger that error?

Comment: Forgot that, sorry. I am trying to debug very simple MariaDB-PDO queries with PHP. It fails even for seven-year-old queries so the issue is not there.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain all information. I don't understand what you are trying to do, and where **exactly** anything is not working as expected

Comment: Nico Haase, I am just trying to make PhpStorm 2021.1 make a connection with Xdebug using <?php phpinfo.php; echo 1/0?> on Fedora Linux. It couldn't be any simpler and it gets debugged just fine in the command line box so the problem doesn't seem to be PHP or Xdebug-related.

Now PhpStorm says it cannot start debugger session with Xdebug 3.0.2 or 3.0.0.

Remember than I'm using an EAP version of PhpStorm.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. I'm using PhpStorm 2020.3.2 with XDebug 3 without any problems - have you tried checking if PhpStorms [debugger validation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/validating-the-configuration-of-the-debugging-engine.html) provides any more details?

Comment: Yes, I ran the validation several times beore writing and finally the connection was made and PhpStorm/Xdebug are working as expected but now I get PDOExceptions on very old code. Since it's an unfinished product I don't think it deserves any more trouble until I can get more information from it. I will write again if I get stuck again. Thanks for your help and your time.

Comment: @PepinhoDoSamba 1) You are using Xdebug v3 ... but keep using v2 param names. They do almost NOTHING in v3. Please check https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide 2) *"PhpStorm's ports are set as 9001 and 9003"* Try changing that so only 1 port is listed there. 3) https://learnxdebug.com/ ; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IN6ihpJSFDw

Comment: Hi, LazyOne. You already helped me in November with a similar issue. The current issue is fixed now because I changed, as you suggest, the Xdebug params to v3 after I started this thread. Anyway it is peculiar that PhpStorm 2020 did work with v2 param names for over a month (I didn't know about param name changes until yesterday) Thanks for learnxdebug.com!!